# Neo4j Spring Boot OGM - saving list of objects in relationship

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have an entity "Track" that has a relationship to a list of track objects (TrackObject).
I have a list of tracks that I want to save to the Neo4j database and each Track has a list of TrackObjects.
Every track gets saved perfectly but only the first TrackObject get saved.
Is there a way to save everything directly?
Here is the Track:

```
@NodeEntity (label="Track")
 public class Track {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;
 Integer number;
 String name;

 @Relationship (type = "IS_IN", direction=Relationship.INCOMING)
 List<TrackObject> objectList;
```

I get my list of Tracks and iterate it:

```
for (Track track : tracks) {
            trackService.saveTrack(track);
            for (TrackObject tobj : track.getObjectList()) {
                trackService.saveTrackObject(tobj);
```

I also tried with "saveAll" and Iterable and it works for the tracks but not for the list of track objects.

```
Iterable<Track> tracks = newImport.getTracks();
     trackService.saveTracks(tracks);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a depth property in save function which has a syntax like 
 void save(T object, int depth);
Please try this.

Comment: No, it doesn't work with depth either, only the first TrackObject get saved as well.

Comment: Can you please debug weather all the track objects are adding in tracks or not.

Comment: yes, they are all there. They display perfectly in the view.

Comment: I think you are saving independently both lists so they wont create a relationship.Try adding trackObjects in each track and then save track.
for (Track track : tracks) {
            for (TrackObject tobj : track.getObjectList()) 
            {
                 track.getobjectList().add(tobj)
           }
            trackService.save(track);
}